# Getting location from from Office 365 Management API's "Client Ip"

Tags: office365

I am getting activity logs of Office 365 accounts using Microsoft Management API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-apis-overview

Logs which I receive are in well structured json format.

For Example:

```
{
  "ObjectId": "8b0a0dbe-8e97-4f87-9518-f7aa140906ca",
  "ApplicationDisplayName": "Microsoft SharePoint Online - SharePoint Home",
  "UserKey": "i:0h.f|membership|10030000ae995947@live.com",
  "ItemType": "Web",
  "Operation": "SearchQueryPerformed",
  "OrganizationId": "2f6cb1a6-ecb8-4578-b680-bf84ded07ff4",
  **"ClientIP": "168.63.48.77",**
  "EventData": "<ClientType>SPHomeOfficeDiscovery</ClientType>",
  "Workload": "SharePoint",
  "EventSource": "SharePoint",
  "RecordType": 4,
  "Version": 1,
  "UserId": "abraban.burwood@emumbapk.onmicrosoft.com",
  "CreationTime": "2019-06-17T23:19:15",
  "Id": "47e39cee-c4f2-48d9-97bd-08d6f37a375d",
  "CorrelationId": "8b0a0dbe-8e97-4f87-9518-f7aa140906ca",
  "ApplicationId": "dcad865d-9257-4521-ad4d-bae3e137b345",
  "UserType": 0
}
```

We are getting location of users from client IP of activity logs. But there are many cases when client IP does not belong to our user e.g. in above activity log client ip 168.63.48.77 belongs to Ireland but we are doing activities from Pakistan and China only.

We have tried excluding those client Ips which belongs to Urls and Ip address ranges provided by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges). But it does not solve issue completely because we still get multiple client ips which does not even belong to Microsoft urls and ip ranges

Is it possible to exclude these logs? How can we differentiate it from client ips of real user?

Comment: Which api do you use

Comment: Using Microsoft Management API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-apis-overview